# How to register an Office 365 Application in Azure AD

Tags: node.js, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create an Office 365 application using node.js and the Microsoft Graph API. I have been following this example, which works well: 
github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample

I am however having serious problems accessing the Azure AD using the Microsoft Graph API. I am trying to do a `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` and `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization` but I am getting a 403 Forbidden. Getting `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` works fine. I would like to be able to create users and groups in the Azure AD of the Office 365 tenant. The user I am using to connect with is a Global Administrator in our `developer` Office 365 tenant.

I believe I need to add `Windows Azure Active Directory` consent permissions on the app registration as read here:
`https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2015/10/06/new-graph-api-consent-permissions/`

BUT that is not possible from the portal which I used to register the `app: apps.dev.microsoft.com`. I have tried to give `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and more, but I get the same error

If I register the app from within the new Azure AD portal: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps the Nodejs application sample does not work after the sign-on. It fails with a “aadsts70001 application `CLIENT_ID` is not supported for this api version”

I have found 3 different Microsoft portals, where you can register Apps and another link suggesting to register the app using PowerShell. In addition as I developer I have to sort through concepts of Azure AD v1, v2, and B2C tenants. There seems to be many pitfalls.

My goal is to create a Multi-Tenant Office 365 application, which integrates with various Office 365 applications and Azure AD using the Microsoft Graph API.

Does anyone know where I went wrong? And what I need to change?

Comment: The problem may be that that the new permission is not yet consented. If the user that you're using has consented before the new delegated permission was added it would not be effective until re-consented. Can you check if the token that you're using has the Directory.ReadWrite.All scope in the scp claim (e.g. using http://jwt.calebb.net/)?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was able to get my code working by doing the things you mentioned. I had to also add the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` to the scope variable of my credentials. Then I needed to clear all cookies to get app to prompt for re-consent. Then it worked.

Comment: However I really wanted this to work without the user needing to consent. I thought that by adding the scope permissions on the application registration "the administrator" of the tenant had consented on behalf of his users. Is that not possible? I does not seem like a good practice to have the regular app users needing to consent to a `Directory.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: If you don't want the user to consent you can use the app-only flow and perform the action as the calling application itself, not on behalf of any user. In this case the permissions of the user calling your app will not be taken into consideration when authorizing your call to MS Graph. When using the delegated flow the action is performed on behalf of the calling user and it's expected that they need to consent to allow your app to perform the action on their behalf. Admin consent for delegated flow allows the use of the app in the tenant, not a consent on behalf of all users of that tenant.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just want to mention that consent will "always" appear at some point or another. If you do what Marek suggested, and do the App Only Flow, you will still need to consent as an administrator before the app can be used for the first time. Also I wanted to address your other comment which was "if you register as an Admin, you don't need consent". This only works when creating applications from the "manage.windowsazure.com" portal

Answer (score 0):

Marek and Shawn already provided the helpful suggestion in the comment. To help other community who have the same issue to recognize the answer for this issue. I would summary it in this reply.

To update the permission when we re-config the permissions for the apps register on Azure, we need to grant the permission again by appending the parameter `prompt=consent`( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code)).

> I have found 3 different Microsoft portals, where you can register Apps and another link suggesting to register the app using PowerShell. In addition as I developer I have to sort through concepts of Azure AD v1, v2, and B2C tenants. There seems to be many pitfalls.

At present, there are two main portals we can register the apps with Azure. First kind is Azure portal([old](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), [new](https://manage.windowsazure.com/)) which we can register the apps integrate with Azure using V1.0 endpoint. And second one is using the Microsoft Application console which we can register the apps integrate with Azure using V2.0 endpoint.

To compare the difference between v1.0 and v2.0 endpoint, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-compare).